# Mapkit annotation image resolution

Tags: iphone, image, annotations, mapkit

I've changed the annotation pin to a custome image, and it works great. However the image looks a little rough around the edges when it drops in the mapview. Does anyone know how to sharpen the image up?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you have the right dpi image and a @2x image? Except that, there's nothing to do.

Comment: I,m not sure. What is the right dpi to use?

Comment: 72dpi, but also @2x images for HiDPI screens

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by using UIGraphicsImageRenderer to create the images. Now they are sharp.

```
let whiteImage = UIImage(named: "white")

let size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)

  let myImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { imageContext in
      let context = imageContext.cgContext
      whiteImage?.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 70, height: 90)))
  }

annotationView!.image = myImage
```